# How to add tasks in the Queue dynamically in google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

For e.g. can i do some thing like this ----
List of namespaces; so iterate over each namespace

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("updateReservation-queue");
for(String name : namespaces){
   queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/CheckExpiryDateTask").param("name", namespace));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can - is there something in particular you're having trouble with?